# OAuth + Google + Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-oauth

## Background

I want to create a PHP application that eventually will be installed on a "countless" web servers.
The application is going to access the Google Drive associated with the web server's administrator Google account (it will basically write some files on user's cloud storage). So my PHP app will be authorized by the end-user to use its Google Drive storage. This is done (via the OAuth2 protocol) by connecting the Google OAuth2 service.

So basically I have to create a ClientID/Secret pair (on behalf of my Google Account) that is gonna be used to execute the authorization flow.

Google provides 3 authorization methods:

1. for web applications (web browsers over network)
2. for service account (my server to Google server)
3. for installed application (like Android, IPhone)

(1) is perhaps the best choice EXCEPT that I have to define a REDIRECT_URI where the authorization code will be sent. Because my APP will be installed on a "countless" different servers I don't know in advance the protocol, domain name and the path (also the URI) where the Google's response should be returned. If I would install this application only on 3 servers I could create upfront a ClientID/Secret pair for each of them. It's not the case.

(2) means to deploy my P12 private key with the PHP application and I don't feel comfortable with that!

(3) means to put the end-user to copy/paste an authorization token from a Google web page into my application web interface. I am trying to avoid doing that.

I already made it to work by using the method 1 when I know in advance the REDIRECT_URI. I also embedded the client_id/secret pair in the source code so the whole authorization process is user-friendly. But this is not going to work on a "countless" deployment scenario.

## Questions

1. Which method and how should I use it in order to make the whole process safe for me (as developer) and for the client too (the web server administrator). Note that the authorization process should not involve the end-user to copy paste some codes. I want that step to be transparent/user-friendly for the end-user (no one likes copy-paste when it can be done automatically).
2. Should I embed my client_id/secret into the application or that's totally wrong? I suppose no end-user wants to go through the creation of its own ClientID in Google Developer Console, right? On the other hand why I would give my client_id/secret to an unknown end-user?

### Final thoughts

I could create a proxy application on my (the developer) web server such that my PHP application (which is supposed to be deployed "everywhere") will send the authorization request to my proxy server (which has already its own client_id/secret) which in turn will redirect the call to the Google OAuth service which then REDIRECT_URI back the authorization code to my proxy and finally I will redirect back the response to the original sender (the PHP application). What do you think?

Some useful answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694432/oauth-2-0-to-access-google-apis-for-wordpress-plugins) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439498/using-oauth-in-wordpress-plugin) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063314/oauth-2-0-for-distributable-web-applications).

@Edit: as I've already said earlier a proxy would be a solution. I've made it and it works. The same solutions I've received also from user **pinoyyid**. Thanks for your answer too.

Comment: As FB OAuth Login Flow says "Your app secret should never end up in client code". This just strengthen my final thoughts above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proxy is the only real option open to you. You can encode the originator URL in the "state" parameter, so that when the proxy receives the access token, it can call a webhook at the originator.

There are some contradictions in your question...
"The application is going to access the Google Drive associated with the web server's administrator Google account" and "So my PHP app will be authorized by the end-user to use its Google Drive storage." are mutually exclusive.

If the Drive storage belongs to the app, then the user isn't involved in any OAuth dialogue.

Could you edit your question to be clear who is the owner of the Drive storage as it greatly influences the OAuth flows.

Comment: The Drive belongs to the end-user (aka web server administrator) and not to the application. I don't see how the 2 statements contradict themselves. The application will access the Drive of the end-user. The end-user MUST authorize my application to access its (end-user) Drive. My application does backups, basically.

Comment: gotcha. we got our terminology mixed. I guess you're distributing your web server code, which is why the usual terminology breaks down slightly. One thing to watch is quota. If all users are sharing the same client/project-id, they will be consuming a common quota. It might be worth decoupling the client-id from your code, such that you can have a pool of id's and shard your users amongst them.