# How to use OAuth 2 in a WordPress plugin without exposing my private credentials?

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I want to develop a WordPress plugin (for backend use) and use OAuth 2 to access the user's Google Search Console data.

As it will be a distributed plugin and whose code will be accessible, I can't use my private credentials.

I have read this question ([OAuth + Google + Wordpress plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833128/oauth-google-wordpress-plugin)) and maybe the solution is to create a proxy that will take care of making the OAuth request and return the authentication to the plugin in WP, but I am not clear how to do it and if to get the refresh token I should still use my private keys in the plugin code.

Could someone tell me if it is possible and how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You should make a settings page for your plugin, where your plugin user would specify his own credentials and use it.

Comment: Yes, for an arbitrary number of websites (URLs) you will need to host a central website at a fixed URL that can act as a proxy. However, despite what people say, you should [avoid using the state parameter](http://www.thread-safe.com/2014/05/the-correct-use-of-state-parameter-in.html) to solve this. Instead, open a window/frame to your proxy site, initiate a session, redirect over to Google for the user to grant permission, handle the redirect back and associate the response with the user's session.

Comment: @oddtwelve, yes, that is the last option, I would like to make it friendly for non-advanced users.